# How to use ajax pagination in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created custom post type 'portfolio' in  my wordpress application.
I am using wp-pagenavi plugin for pagination of custom posts.Can anyone guide me how will I implement ajax pagination i.e load newer posts without reloading the whole page. Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

```
/*******ajax pagination*******/
jQuery(document).on('click', '#pagination a', function(e){  
  e.preventDefault();  
  var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');  
  jQuery('#content').html('Loading...');  //the 'main' div is inside the 'content' div
  jQuery('#content').load(link+' #main');
});
```

the .live() function has been depreciated so use .on() instead.
obviously the jQuery library is needed too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of options you can try:

[AJAXify WordPress Tutorial](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/how-to-ajaxify-wordpress-theme.html)

[AJAXify WordPress Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajaxify-wordpress-site/)

I've used the first option, its a good tutorial.  I know it works.  You may need to modify it some though.  I cannot vouch for the second option as I've never used it.  Just a quick Google search turned it up though.